# VSCode Volar Intellisense doesn't work in WSL

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, volar

Intellisense doesn't work in Vue components. When I hover over something I want info on, it just shows "Loading...". This only happens when using VSCode through WSL, in Windows Volar works just fine.

I'm in a Nuxt 3 project using Typescript. The only plugins activated are WSL and Volar. Volar takeover mode is active.

Output when hovering a function

[image: img]

I've tried reinstalling Volar, also tried deleting the .vscode-server folder in WSL.

Comment: Did you check that the extension is installed in VSCode WSL?

Comment: Yes, made sure extension is installed on WSL